# How to show road arrow in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, openstreetmap

I've downloaded OSM file and extracted it to PostgreSQL. Now I have 4 layers:

- planet_osm_line
- planet_osm_point
- planet_osm_polygon
- planet_osm_roads

I added these layers to GeoServer and set SLD file for each of them but after rendering road arrow is not shown. 
I need something like this:

[image]

What should I do to show these arrows?

Comment: I know it's been 2 years, but do you remember what you ended up doing about this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps You have to set correct layers display order that Your planet_osm_point layer is rendered last?
https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/layergroups.html#edit-a-layer-group